# What is the purpose of additional CGAL targets that are generated by cmake

Tags: cmake, cgal

I have installed CGAL and added it to myProject via cmake:

```
find_package(CGAL REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(myProject PRIVATE CGAL::CGAL)
```

I can use CGAL in myProject without problems, however it adds the following targets in cmake (or in Visual Studio the respective projects to my solution):
Continuous, Experimental, Nightly, NightlyMemoryCheck

I wasn't able to find any documentation on what their purpose is. The ["How to use CGAL with CMake" wiki page](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/wiki/How-to-use-CGAL-with-CMake-or-your-own-build-system) doesn't mention them either.

The names could suggest that they might be used if one wants to contribute to CGAL. Is that correct or do they have another purpose? Can these targets be disabled if I don't need them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those targets are created by the `CTest` module of CMake, that CGAL includes. Actually, it should not include it because CGAL does not really uses it. My mistake. The pull-request [CGAL/cgal#3657](https://github.com/CGAL/cgal/pull/3657) will fix that in the development branch of CGAL, and soon in CGAL-4.14.